# How does a C++ std::container (vector) store its internals (element address, access by index)?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, std, stdvector

I am trying to "hack" a game (Red Alert 3), I try to make a program which shows the unit list of my opponents. As for that I first need to find a (static) pointer to my own list which I can do on single player.

I have noticed this behaviour: (by looking at which addresses are changed by the add_unit code):

- if a units hasn't been build yet, create a new address for it (random?) and set the value to 1 (amount of units of that type)
- when the unit has been already build once in the game, increment the original address of the unit type by 1

This looks to me like  std::vector behaviour. Now I am having trouble to find the "base" address of the vector, and a bigger problem: How would I access by index? Where does a std::vector store it's addresses it has for elements?

Extra info:

The code is (from what I have read from the assembly) compiled with MS Visual C++ 2005 (MSVCR80 dll's are required to play)

This is what the addresses in the vector look like:

[image]

(The highlighted address is the one which appeared as the first element - first unit build)

This doesn't look like I could iterate by adding a constant value?

Whenever a new address is added, all the other addresses are perfectly valid and don't change.

Comment: Completely depends on the implementation provided by the compiler vendor. The standard only describes the interface and what requirements you have on the container, not implementation details.

Comment: Guys… questions don't have to be defined by the language standard to be valid. He's asking about a publicly available, compiled program which is available to everyone. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: the code is (from what I have read from the assembly) compiled with MS Visual C++ 2008 (MSVCR80 dll's are required to play)

Comment: Standard also prescribes that vector store it's objects in contiguous memory. So if you have the base address, you can get the address for any element as an offset from the base address.

Comment: Linking against `MSVCRT80.DLL` etc. suggests that the application was built with Visual Studio 2005 (also known as "MSVC8"). Visual Studio 2008 (also known as "MSVC9") would use `MSVCRT90.DLL` etc..

Comment: oh sorry my bad, fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical (though by no means mandatory) implementation of `vector` is to have three consecutive words:

```
struct TypicalVector
{
    T * start;
    T * end;
    T * capacity;
};
```

Element access is done via `start[i]` (which is why it's important to have the `start` pointer at the front, to avoid unnecessary offset computations), size is `end - start`, and capacity is `capacity - start`. Memory allocation obtains `c * sizeof(T)` bytes and sets `start` to the address of the allocated memory and `capacity` to `start + c`. Element construction increments `end`.

Comment: I noticed that the new adresses which are added are sometimes lower, and sometimes bigger than the first added address, does this mean that start is changing to the lowest address?

Comment: @GamErix: It's a dynamic container, so the entire buffer is reallocated when the capacity needs to grow.

Comment: Yet the adresses always work (don't change) while in-game, so how is it done? :o

Comment: @GamErix: Ask the developers?! Who says that the data is even in a contiguous array? It could be any other kind of data structure... (a deque, or a linked list perhaps?)

Comment: is there somewhere documented internals for all data structures so I can try them all out? :)

Comment: @GamErix: Look at the source of the vendor's standard library. (I believe that's MS VC++ 6 for the game you mention.)